# iOS giving plotsymbols a border

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I am trying to create a simple scatter plot with PlotSymbols for when I hit a point of data. I have all of that implemented, but the line and the symbols are all one color that blends in making it hard to see the data. I know I could make the symbols bigger, but I am hoping to try and avoid that.

From the few screen shots that I saw in the examples I saw the ability to do this, but only for the ellipse symbol. Is there any way to do this for other symbols as I am currently using the rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every plot symbol has a `lineStyle` and a `fill`. You can mix and match to get whatever look you want.